# Solving system of ODE and Equilibrium points

Tags: differential-equations, stability

This is the first time I am using Mathematica and I am trying to solve the system of ODE,
$\dot x=x(1-x)-\frac{2xy}{y+x}\qquad\dot y=-1.5y+\frac{2xy}{y+x}$

When I used `Nsolve` or `DSolve` it gives errors.

[image]

Then I tried to find equilibrium points,
[image]

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong. This is the first time I am using Mathematica.

Comment: Please put code as something other people can copy into their *Mathematica* session, instead of screenshots.

Comment: Try sol = {x[t], y[t]} /. NDSolve[{x'[t]==x[t](1-x[t])-2 x[t] y[t]/(y[t]+x[t]), y'[t]==-3/2 y[t]+2 x[t]y[t]/(y[t]+x[t]), x[0]==1, y[0]==2}, {x[t],y[t]}, {t,0,10}][[1]] and follow that with Plot[sol, {t,0,10}] Then substitute appropriate initial conditions for x[0] and y[0]

Comment: With respect to the second part of your question, one of the curly brackets is misplaced.  Try this instead: `Solve[{x[t] (1 - x[t]) - 2 x[t] y[t]/(y[t] + x[t]) == 0, -3/2 y[t] + 2 x[t] y[t]/(y[t] + x[t]) == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}]`.

Comment: @Bill In, `{x[t], y[t]} /. 
 NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t]) - 2 x[t] y[t]/(y[t] + x[t]), 
    y'[t] == -3/2 y[t] + 2 x[t] y[t]/(y[t] + x[t]), x[0] == 1, 
    y[0] == 2}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 10}][[1]]` what does `{x[t], y[t]} /. ` and `[[1]]` do? When I do it as, `solve2 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 
    x[t] (1 - x[t]) - (2 x[t] y[t]/(y[t] + x[t])), 
   y'[t] == -1.5 y[t] + (2 x[t] y[t]/(y[t] + x[t])), x[0] == 1, 
   y[0] == 2}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]` why doesn't it give any output? Also, can't I use `DSolve`

Comment: To answer your questions, if you leave off both the {x[t],y[t]}/. and [[1]] and look at the output then you will see {{x[t]->stuff1, y[t]->stuff2}} when what Plot needs is {stuff1, stuff2}. Thus the extra bits I added give you what Plot needs. Your solve2 version shows me output, but not in a form that Plot can understand. Look up both /. and -> in the help system, those will really help you. I first tried DSolve, it took so long that I thought it would never finish, I tried multiplying to get rid of denominators, same, I switched to NDSolve and it instantly gave a solution.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your system of ODE's numerically, you need two initial conditions. Here I choose random ones.

```
Eq1 = x'[t] == x[t]*(1 - x[t]) - 2*x[t]*y[t]/(x[t] + y[t]);

Eq2 = y'[t] == -1.5*y[t] + 2*x[t]*y[t]/(x[t] + y[t]);

sol = NDSolve[{Eq1, Eq2, x[0] == 2, y[0] == 1}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];

Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Solve[{x*(1 - x) - 2*x*y/(x + y) == 0, -1.5*y + 2*x*y/(x + y) == 0}, {x, y}]
```

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.

To get rid of the above warring, use fraction instead of decimal.

```
Solve[{x*(1 - x) - 2*x*y/(x + y) == 0, Rationalize[-1.5]*y + 2*x*y/(x + y) == 0}, {x, y}]
```

> {{x -> 1/2, y -> 1/6}, {x -> 1, y -> 0}}